# Detect Window's Default Media Player

Tags: python, wxpython, media

I'm trying to detect Window's default media player path so that I can access it from my Python/wxPython program. My specific need is to make a list of all media files and play it using the player.

Comment: My advice is to not try to detect any internal details of the system, but use `os.system` to make the system "open" the files with whatever it thinks appropriate application.

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thanks :)

Comment: Only problem is that it fails when there is a space in the path.

Comment: Wrap the file path in quotes. e.g. "C:\My Documents", not C:\My Documents

Comment: Why not just use `os.startfile(path)`? You won't need to put anything in quotes.

Comment: Turns out what I need is subprocess, using os.system just stops my program from running until the opened program gets closed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments above, it looks like you decided to go in another direction with this. Your question made me curious though so I did some hunting around anyway.

File associations are stored in the Windows Registry. The way to access Windows Registry information via python is to use the _winreg module (available in versions 2.0 and later). Individual file association information for the current user will be stored at subkeys named as follows:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.wmv\UserChoices`

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mpeg\UserChoices`

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.avi\UserChoices`

etc, etc for any specific file format you are looking for.

Here is a small example script I've written to access this information and store it as a list:

```
import _winreg as wr

# Just picked three formats - feel free to substitute or extend as needed
videoFormats = ('.wmv', '.avi', '.mpeg')

#Results written to this list
userOpenPref = []

for i in videoFormats:
    subkey = ("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion" + 
                "\\Explorer\\FileExts\\" + i + "\\UserChoice")

    explorer = wr.OpenKey(wr.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey)

    try:
        i = 0
        while 1:
            # _winreg.EnumValue() returns a tuple:
            # (subkey_name, subkey_value, subkey_type)
            # For this key, these tuples would look like this:
            # ('ProgID', '<default-program>.AssocFile.<file-type>', 1).
            # We are interested only in the value at index 1 here
            userOpenPref.append(wr.EnumValue(explorer, i)[1])
            i += 1
    except WindowsError:
        print

    explorer.Close()

print userOpenPref
```

Output:

`[u'WMP11.AssocFile.WMV', u'WMP11.AssocFile.avi', u'WMP11.AssocFile.MPEG']`

with WMP11 = Windows Media Player 11

Hope this was helpful.

Sources:

[python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html), [effbot tutorial](http://effbot.org/librarybook/winreg.htm)